# Display number of results from mysql based on two select options

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

I have the following `HTML` code that allows me to select two items from select dropdown options; 
Now, after selecting the two items, say, I select accommodation as my form and Kampala as my district, I want the total number of available possible results, for example, "25 results were found", to be automatically displayed.

The problem I have is that only the results for one selection are displayed with the other being shown as undefined notice. Any assistance please.

```
<!-- here is the html script for selecting options -->    

<form id="analysis_formId" method="POST">

<label>select form</label>
<select id="selectformId" name="selectform" class="select_elements">
<option value="afc">accommodation form</option>
<option value="rtt">tour and travel form</option>   
</select>

<label>select district</label>

<select id="selectdistrictsId" name="selectdistricts" class="select_elements">
<option value="alldistricts">All districts</option>
<option value="kampala">kampala</option>
<option value="wakiso">wakiso</option>   
</select>        
</form>

<!-- displaying results from count.php -->
<p><span id="inspection_result"></span></p>
```

This the script that gets the class names of the select elements and runs the `onChange` event.

```
<script>
var selections = document.getElementsByClassName("select_elements");
function onchangefunction(){
var selectedstring = (this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);
$("#inspection_result").html('checking...');                                            
$.ajax({
type:'POST',
url:'count.php',
data:$(this).serialize(),
success:function(data)
{
$("#inspection_result").html(data);
}
});
}

for (var i = 0, l = selections.length; i < l; i++) {
selections[i].onchange = onchangefunction;
}
</script>
```

Here is *count.php* for querying the results from `MySQL`

```
if($_POST) 
{
$formtype     = strip_tags($_POST['selectform']);
$selectdistricts     = strip_tags($_POST['selectdistricts']);


$fetchallforms22 = $conn->prepare("select count(indexId) as numafcrtt2 
from registered_companies where company_form_type=:formtype and company_district=:selectdistricts");

$fetchallforms22->execute(array(':formtype'=>$formtype, ':selectdistricts'=>$selectdistricts));

$display22 = $fetchallforms22->fetchObject();           

if($display22){

echo $display22->numafcrtt2." "."results available";
}
else
{
echo $display22->numafcrtt2." "."results available";
}
}//POST
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe no results for this query, chech it:

```
if (!empty(display2) ){
..... // DO something
}
```

Comment: #Peter, I have edited that, it wasn't supposed to be there...Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Come on guys, some assistance please. Its taking me ages to come up with a solution for this.